# phpmyadmin Error Processing request 403 forbidden

Tags: phpmyadmin

when i try to edit some columns in tables in the phpmyadmin i am getting the error :

error in processing request 403 forbidden

I had hosted my php application to a cloud server which is running on linux (centos 6.6)

please help.

Comment: im facing the similar issue. do you have the solution ?

Answer (score 0):

By looking at my log files, **mod_security** does this (CentOS 7 user here). I disabled it and all ran perfectly normal. I guess it gets buggy from time to time.